# How do i convert a dynamic web project in eclipse to run from an icon on desktop?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse.  It has html files, Css file, js files, java files, jsp files, and etc.  It also is connected to an oracle database, which the dynamic web project inserts, updates, deletes and shows data into webpage.  The web project works fine in eclipse IDE, and can run it on the external web browser.

I need to take the dynamic web project and put it on the desktop, such as a shortcut icon.  So, i want to be able to open the web project from the desktop and be able to run directly on the web browser, like chrome.  The reason is I need to send that web project to other users to test, and see if what changes needs to be made.  The users do not have eclipse on their systems.  Is there a way I can send them the app. as a desktop application?

If not, Can anybody help me on how I can do it on my local system?

Comment: move it to a server and give them the url

Comment: You could use a JEditorPane and display your html in it. I haven't tried it with JSP, but it will display html, css, etc.

Comment: @oldercoder god idea for plain HTML. But with JSP and Java involved, this sounds like an application with a backend that has to be run in a Java application server (e.g. Tomcat or Wildfly)

Comment: @isaace, thanks.  That helped me from going into eclipse every time to run the app

Answer (score 0):

For the run of web_application with some jsp-files you need to have one servlet container as Tomcat or Jboss, Wildfly e.t.c. This container must be for you available over the network ( mayby official IP-Address is necessary). Then you can access to URL of your web-application with your local browser and observe the work of your application. With the icon and one link you can start the web browser with your required URL too.